# LWC won't nest in a community

Tags: lightning-web-components, community, html

I am having issues with rendering a nested LWC in a community. If the template is all in one place it works all fine but, if I try to move a part of this in a separate component, I have the following exception in the preview:

```
{"subject":"router level error","message":"t.loadContent is not a function","stack":"TypeError: t.loadContent is not a function\n at Proxy._showTabContentForTabValue (modules/interop/tabset.js:1:2937)\n at Proxy._selectTab (modules/interop/tabset.js:1:2613)\n at Proxy.handleTabRegister (modules/interop/tabset.js:1:2545)\n at u.apply (https://resilient-fox-9pyuyq-dev-ed.livepreview.salesforce-communities.com/webruntime/framework/b36e8819/prod/locker:2:46749)\n at es (https://resilient-fox-9pyuyq-dev-ed.livepreview.salesforce-communities.com/webruntime/framework/0251dbf7/prod/app:9:12959)\n at https://resilient-fox-9pyuyq-dev-ed.livepreview.salesforce-communities.com/webruntime/framework/0251dbf7/prod/app:9:11197\n at ws (https://resilient-fox-9pyuyq-dev-ed.livepreview.salesforce-communities.com/webruntime/framework/0251dbf7/prod/app:9:16489)\n at $a (https://resilient-fox-9pyuyq-dev-ed.livepreview.salesforce-communities.com/webruntime/framework/0251dbf7/prod/app:9:11181)\n at https://resilient-fox-9pyuyq-dev-ed.livepreview.salesforce-communities.com/webruntime/framework/0251dbf7/prod/app:9:6569\n at https://resilient-fox-9pyuyq-dev-ed.livepreview.salesforce-communities.com/webruntime/framework/0251dbf7/prod/app:1:39201","wcstack":"\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t","location":{"hostname":"resilient-fox-9pyuyq-dev-ed.livepreview.salesforce-communities.com","pathname":"/"}}
```

The father LWC is the following:

*father.html*

```
<template>
    <lightning-tabset>
        <c-week-one></c-week-one>
    </lightning-tabset>
</template>
```

while the *weekOne.html* is

```
<lightning-tab label="Week 1" value="1" onactive={handleActive}>
    <div class="slds-grid">
        <div class="slds-size_1-of-6">
            <lightning-vertical-navigation>
                <lightning-vertical-navigation-section>
                    <lightning-vertical-navigation-item label="Day 1" name="day1"></lightning-vertical-navigation-item>
                    <lightning-vertical-navigation-item label="Day 2" name="day2"></lightning-vertical-navigation-item>
                </lightning-vertical-navigation-section>
            </lightning-vertical-navigation>     
        </div>
    </div>
</lightning-tab>
```

Could you support me to understand why this is happening?

Thanks!

Comment: not clear what you mean by "breaks" or "not working"

Comment: I was meaning that the preview raises an exception, even if the LWC seems correct. I edited the Question to be clearer